# How can I create a SIP connecton using Liblinphone interface class?

Tags: java, android, interface, linphone, object-initializers

Want to develop a SIP client for Android using Liblinphone library.
There is a LinphoneAuthInfo class that accepts authentication.
And a LinphoneCore.addAuthInfo() That adds authentication info to the core.

**The problem is that I cannot initialize LinphoneAuthInfo and LinphoneCore classes because they are interface classes and I don't know how to use theme.**

If they was not interface classes I would do this:

```
// Create Authentication object
LinphoneAuthInfo authInfos;
authInfos.setDomain(id);
authInfos.setUserId(username);
authInfos.setPassword(password);

// Config Core
LinphoneCore linCore;
linCore.addAuthInfo(authInfos);
```

And finaly, this is the Liblinphone reference page:

> http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/org/linphone/core/LinphoneCore.html
>   http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/org/linphone/core/LinphoneAuthInfo.html

Comment: if you don't know how to "use" Interfaces, you really can't develop Android apps yet...

Comment: Thanks my friend. I know that an interface is a shell for classes. They have no method implementation. Is this right? Then where is the implementation of this methods? Do you have any reference or sample code?

Comment: Have you tried to google "java interface tutorial"?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Everybody cannot know it all, perhaps this why developers ask questions on StackOverflow, Google, and other platforms.

Comment: @CWilliams, you realise you answered to a comment I gave more than three years ago??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Yeah, I do. Currently working on a SIP project at the moment.

Comment: @CWilliams, well, good luck to you. you should have known better than post your snide comment on something that much old

Comment: thanks @sheron ben asher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely an interface cannot be initialized. Because it has no method implementation. It's not a class!

I should use classes that implement these methods.

In fact I should use **org.linphone.core** (Library) instead of **LinphoneCore** (Intreface)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this on the java website. This is a way to use interfaces:

```
public interface OperateCar {
   // constant declarations, if any
   // method signatures

   // An enum with values RIGHT, LEFT
   int turn(Direction direction,
            double radius,
            double startSpeed,
            double endSpeed);
   int changeLanes(Direction direction,
                   double startSpeed,
                   double endSpeed);
   int signalTurn(Direction direction,
                  boolean signalOn);
   int getRadarFront(double distanceToCar,
                     double speedOfCar);
   int getRadarRear(double distanceToCar,
                    double speedOfCar);
         ......
   // more method signatures
}


public class OperateBMW760i implements OperateCar {

    // the OperateCar method signatures, with implementation --
    // for example:
    int signalTurn(Direction direction, boolean signalOn) {
       // code to turn BMW's LEFT turn indicator lights on
       // code to turn BMW's LEFT turn indicator lights off
       // code to turn BMW's RIGHT turn indicator lights on
       // code to turn BMW's RIGHT turn indicator lights off
    }

    // other members, as needed -- for example, helper classes not 
    // visible to clients of the interface
}
```

More information can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

I hope this helps

Comment: this site really isn't the place for language tutorials

Comment: @sharonbn This is just an awnser to the asked question, im just trying to help

Comment: Sometimes the best help is pointing the person in the right direction outside of this forum